# Determining the dates of days

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time

I'm trying to use `WeatherData[]` to give me (not sure how) the temperature, humidity, wind-speed, cloud cover... at a certain location.

I only want the information for weekdays (e.g. Monday-Friday) for the last 83 years.

How do I make a list of all these dates in a format (`DateList` or `DateString`) that `WeatherData[]` can use?

Comment: Search for `DayOfWeek` in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

For variation, here  is method that doesn't require the `Calendar` package and uses a function which returns days of the week ranging from 0 for Sunday to 6 for Saturday:

```
GaussDay[y_Integer, m_Integer, d_Integer] := 
 With[{yDigits = IntegerDigits[y - Boole[m < 3]},
  With[{ y1 = FromDigits[yDigits[[1 ;; 2]]], 
    y2 = FromDigits[yDigits[[3 ;; 4]]]}, 
   Mod[(d + Floor[2.6 ( Mod[m + 9, 12] + 1) - 0.2] + y2 + 
      Quotient[y2, 4] + Quotient[y1, 4] - 2 y1), 7]]]
```

And in play:

```
Select[WeatherData["Chicago", 
  "Temperature", {{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 11}}], 
 MemberQ[Range@5, GaussDay @@ #[[1, 1 ;; 3]]] &]
```

For comparison, this took about 8.5 seconds to select approx 130,000 measurements when asked for 83 years of data.

Comment: `Floor[y2/4]` is better expressed as `Quotient[y2, 4]`.

Comment: This is a good solution. As a rule of thumb, never use Mathematica's built-in date functions unless you absolutely have to. By my tests, they are two orders of magnitude slower than Visual Basic's comparable functions, and even farther behind compiled languages.

Comment: Also, I prefer [Larsen's method](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184409541) myself for day-of-week computations: `larsen[{yr_Integer, mo_Integer, da_Integer}] := Module[{y = yr, m = mo, d = da, f, q}, If[m < 3, y--; m += 12]; f = If[y >= 1752 && m >= 9 && d >= 14, Quotient[y, 400] - Quotient[y, 100], 5]; q = d + 2 m + 1 + Quotient[3 (m + 1), 5] + y + Quotient[y, 4] + f; Mod[q, 7] + 1]`. No digit twiddling necessary; just integer arithmetic.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you.

Comment: `If[m < 3, IntegerDigits[y - 1], IntegerDigits[y]]` might be better written as `IntegerDigits[y - Boole[m < 3]]`.

Answer (score 4):

After testing the performance of my first answer, along with J.M.'s suggestion, I don't think it will be fast enough.  Here is another approach: filtering after acquisition.

This gives all `"Temperature"` data for Chicago in 2011, filtering out all Saturdays and Sundays.

```
Select[
  WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature", {{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}}],
  ! MatchQ[DateString[#[[1]], "DayName"], "Saturday" | "Sunday"] &
]
```

If you only want one point for each day, use:  `{{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"}`

Comment: No need for the Calendar package. The built-in `DateString[{2011, 1, 1}, {"DayName"}]` will do (and is slightly faster too). Note that it returns day names as strings instead of symbols.

Comment: @Sjoerd thanks!  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Load the Calendar package:

```
Needs["Calendar`"]
```

Find a Sunday:

```
DayOfWeek[{1950, 1, 1}] (* Sunday *)
```

Create a list of offsets from that day for weekdays:

```
weeks = 10;
offsets = Join @@ Array[Range@5 + 7 # &, weeks, 0];
```

Generate resolved days from offsets:

```
weekdays = DaysPlus[{1950, 1, 1}, #]& /@ offsets;
```

Confirm:

```
Tally[DayOfWeek /@ weekdays]
```

> ```
> {{Monday, 10}, {Tuesday, 10}, {Wednesday, 10}, {Thursday, 10}, {Friday, 10}}
> ```

Comment: After which, OP can do something like `Outer[WeatherData["Chicago", #1, #2] &, {"Temperature", "Humidity", "WindSpeed", "CloudCoverFraction"}, weekdays, 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: @J.M. okay; I was leaving *something* for the OP to figure out. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sure in the long run I'd appreciate it, but right now... No.  (I'm just in a hurry.)

Comment: Wizard: I figured that use of `Outer[]` is not too well-known among beginners, so I figured it should be pointed out... :)

Comment: @J.M. you're right, and that comment upvote is mine.